Recursive Functions and Vector Spaces
In linear algbera we learn that a vector space $V$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication such that any vector $v$ in $V$ is a linear combination of some basis set $S$. In discrete math we learn that a function is recursively defined when there exists some basis $f(0)=a$ for $f(n) = kf(n-1)$.
These concepts seem similar but is it right to say that a vector space is recursively defined by its basis? And if not can a vector space even be recursively defined? My gut feeling is that closure would not hold, but I am still new to mathematics, so any help would be appreciated!
Edit: For clarification to whpowell96's point, for this problem I only wish to consider every vector space with a basis, such that its basis is also a recursive basis.

You can define a vector space as just a collection of elements with the proper algebraic operations. The fact that every vector space has a basis requires the Axiom of Choice (via Zorn’s Lemma)

@whpowell96 , why would Axiom of Choice be necessary for finite dimensional vector space having a basis? I remember induction.

I don’t think OP specified that the vector space in question is finite-dimensional. A basis can define a vector space but a basis is not necessary to define a vector space technically

Closure under various algebraic operations can be viewed in a kind of inductive way. See Arturo Magidin's answer to The $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ generated by a set $\mathcal{A}$ is the smallest sigma algebra including $\mathcal{A}$, along with 3. Monotone Closure Operators in this mathoverflow answer -- note the example (2) The set of linear combinations of a subset of a vector space) in connection with Fixed Points of Monotone Closure Operators (iterative or “from below” approach).
